# Add an identifier when a space is followed by four digits

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I am dealing with a String,

```
30-Nov-2012 30-Nov-2012 United Kingdom, 31-Oct-2012 31-Oct-2012 United Arab Emirates, 29-Oct-2012 31-Oct-2012 India
```

I need to add spaces every time a space appears after a four digit numbers, i.e.:

```
30-Nov-2012@30-Nov-2012@United Kingdom, 31-Oct-2012@31-Oct-2012@United Arab Emirates, 29-Oct-2012@31-Oct-2012@India
```

I don't know how to write Regular Expressions, any help please?

Comment: Well, have you tried to *learn* how to write regular expressions? Have you read the documentation for java.util.regex.Pattern?

Comment: You want to add '@' every time a space appears after a four digit numbers as seen in your example

Comment: KishorSharma yes, you are correct. 
JonSkeet please can you share appropriate resources ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know how to write Regular Expressions, your best bet is learning how to use Regular Expressions.

Here's a pretty good tutorial.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

The expression you want to write doesn't seem very complicated. You should be able to do it after going through this tutorial.

Edit: Here's another hint. Take a look at [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll)

and also take a look at [positive lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Edit2: I'm bored, so here's the answer.

```
string.replaceAll("(?<=\\d{4})\\s", "@");
```

Comment: Give it a try and see if it works. There are a bunch of sites online that let you test regular expressions. Here's one: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: @onkar I updated my answer with a possible solution. Let me know if it doesn't work (it should).

Comment: Try again, I forgot to paste it as code so it lost some '\'s.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
(\d{4})\s+
```

replace with

```
$1@
```

and a sample code:

```
String result = inputString.replaceAll("(\\d{4})\\s+", "$1@");
```

explain:

> ***`\d`***
>   Matches any decimal digit.
>
> ***`{n}`***
>   Matches the previous element exactly `n` times.
>
> ***`\s`***
>   Matches any `white-space` character.
>
> ***`+`***
>   Matches the previous element one or more times.
>
> ***`(subexpression)`***
>   Captures the matched subexpression and assigns it a zero-based ordinal number.
>
> ***`$ number`***
>   Substitutes the substring matched by group number.