# Is it more efficient to use a positive look-behind or a back reference?

Tags: java, regex

[Using the code of a question I just answered as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152866/add-an-identifier-when-a-space-is-followed-by-four-digits/13152957#13152957)

Starting with the string

```
30-Nov-2012 30-Nov-2012 United Kingdom, 31-Oct-2012 31-Oct-2012 United
Arab Emirates, 29-Oct-2012 31-Oct-2012 India
```

What if we wanted to replace the space after every four-digit number with an `@` such that you end up with something like this:

```
30-Nov-2012@30-Nov-2012@United Kingdom, 31-Oct-2012@31-Oct-2012@United
Arab Emirates, 29-Oct-2012@31-Oct-2012@India
```

How much more efficient is it to use a back-reference rather than a positive lookbehind (if at all)?

back-reference:

```
inputString.replaceAll("(\\d{4})\\s", "$1@");
```

positive lookbehind:

```
inputString.replaceAll("(?<=\\d{4})\\s", "@");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I admit my testing methodology is crude and may be flawed (furthermore I don't know Java, only learning enough to write this answer), but my initial evidence proves contrary to @dasblinkenlight's answer. I ran the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    private static void test (String regex, String replace, int repetitions)
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++)
        {
            String str = "30-Nov-2012 United Kingdom, 31-Oct-2012 31-Oct-2012 United Arab Emirates, 29-Oct-2012 31-Oct-2012 India, ";
            str.replaceAll(regex, replace);
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Execution time: " + Long.toString(endTime - startTime));
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        test("(\\d{4})\\s", "$1@", 10000);
        test("(?<=\\d{4})\\s", "@", 10000);
        test("(\\d{4})\\s", "$1@", 10000);
        test("(?<=\\d{4})\\s", "@", 10000);
        test("(\\d{4})\\s", "$1@", 10000);
        test("(?<=\\d{4})\\s", "@", 10000);
        test("(\\d{4})\\s", "$1@", 10000);
        test("(?<=\\d{4})\\s", "@", 10000);
    }
}
```

...here, http://ideone.com/WkHLMN, and the output was:

```
Execution time: 164
Execution time: 140
Execution time: 96
Execution time: 135
Execution time: 95
Execution time: 133
Execution time: 94
Execution time: 130
```

Ignoring the first set of cases as outliers having to do with initialization, the remainder cases seem to indicate that the *latter* expression, using the positive lookbehind assertion, might do as much as 50% more work! I suspect this may be the case because backreferences would require going *back* to check whether an assertion is true, *after* passing the characters of interest.

Comment: Finding things out through actually measuring. I approve!

Answer (score 5):

There is no back-reference in your first example, it's a reference to a numbered *capturing group* in the output.

The efficiency of the search in both cases is the same; the difference is only in what is captured. Therefore, the overall difference in performance will boil down to the differences in replacing string content: in the first case, two strings are combined to form a replacement, while in the second case only one string is used. Theoretically, the first case should require slightly more work, but in practice it is unlikely that the difference would be noticeable.

**EDIT:** As the tests by [acheong87](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925913/acheong87) show, using positive lookahead is nearly 50% less efficient in Java. Moreover, this inefficiency does not appear to be Java-specific (although its magnitude in Java is overwhelming: [a C# program equivalent to `acheong87`'s](http://ideone.com/vafueM) shows a slowdown of about 24% under Mono and about 21% under Windows).

I guess the take-home lesson of this exercise is that theoretical near-equivalence of expressions does not guarantee equivalent timing in practice: there is no substitution to profiling of the actual implementation.

Comment: Thanks, exactly the kind of answer that I was looking for.

Comment: @Michael The tutorial is slightly misleading: back reference happens when you refer to the capturing group within the same expression, for example `"([A-Z])-\\1"`. This will match `A-A`, `B-B`, `C-C`, and so on; in this case, `\\1` is a back reference, because it refers "back" to a group that has been captured previously. When you use `$1` syntax in a replacement string, it's simply a way to refer to a capturing group.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I trust your intuition more than I trust my testing; would you kindly examine my answer and let me know your thoughts?

Comment: @acheong87 Very interesting -- it looks like there is some additional work associated with *not* capturing the content of the positive look-behind. This looks very strange, because the efficiency of the two should be the same, at least theoretically.

Comment: +1 (after the edit). I agree with your theoretical explanation (and disagree with my own postulate as to why one might be slower). I would assume a regular expressions engine, encountering a lookbehind, knowing lookbehinds are fixed-length, would use a queue structure to test the assertion "as it runs", so no "going back" is required. I'm sure there is a good answer to where the overhead occurs, but I can't imagine what it is...